# Pressing the back button calls onDestory() method, is there any way not to do so, I mean ignoring the onDestory() method from being called

Tags: java, android

I have a requirement where, whenever the user press the back button it shouldn't do call  to onDestory() method. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: please explain more properly what you want when back button pressed.

Comment: i just created a service which runs in background even if the app is killed explicitly and it worked fine but there is a bug. whenever the user press the back button (service is still running in the back) but if after that user kills the app service also get killed. But if the user press home button and then kill the app service still runs in the background but the same is not working when the user press back button. So i was wondering if i disable the onDestory() method whenever user press back button it may will work.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way not to do so

You can use this

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

add your own functionalities , if you require